# Python: file.readline adding a space at the end of the line

Tags: python

Am using python to read a flat space-padded text file. Part of the validation of the text file is that each line in the text file is expected to be a specific file length including the space padding.

When I use the following code, python ends up giving me a line with an extra space. E.g. I expect all the rows in fileX to have 143 characters. Python though will read this as 144 characters and thus say the file is invalid. If I do the same in VB.NET, I get the correct 143 characters.

Why is **Python's** readline function adding an extra character? (Using python 3.2)

```
import io
myfile = open("file_path", "r")
while True:
    line = myfile.readline()
    if not line:
            break
    print(len(line))  #This prints 144 characters
```

**VB.NET** gives the correct length of 143 characters.

```
Using objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myFilePath)
    While objStreamReader.EndOfStream = False
            line = objStreamReader.ReadLine
            len(line)   'This returns the correct length of 143.
```

Using line.strip will not be the right mechanism because I might get rid of useful spaces. Remember the file is space-padded up to a maximum given length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`objStreamReader.ReadLine` [chops off the terminating newline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx), whereas Python's `file.readline` [keeps it](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

If your file was opened in text mode (and unless you explicitly specified otherwise, it was), the line ending will always be either nothing (last line only) or exactly one `\n`, and you can safely chop it off with `rstrip('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

The 144th character is a newline character.

```
with open("file_path") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip("\n") # strip newline
        print(len(line)) # should print 143
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension, you can do this as below:

```
def readfile():
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fh.readlines()]
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
```